# Box2D - Proper way to simulate player's body and feet

Tags: libgdx, box2d, body

I'm new to LibGDX and Box2D, and I'm trying to create my player's body but got some issues.

I've created the ground as a ChainShape, and my player as a Rectangle. I want to attach a fixture for its feet, so I tried adding an EdgeShape but - correct me if I'm wrong- it seems that an EdgeShape cannot collide with a ChainShape.

Is there a proper way to create the player's feet? Should I change my ground from ChainShape to Rectangles or should I use some other shape for the feet?

**Edit:**
Following DMGregory's advice, I've made some progress.
Since my print statements won't be of much help, I'll post this link with a very detailed explanation: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459208/distinguish-between-collision-surface-orientations-in-box2d

And some background reading here:
https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy

Comment: Is a rectangle for the player not sufficient for your case? Can you show us what your character and its collision shapes look like at the moment?

Comment: I'm just using a 32x64 rectangle at the moment. I have some moving platforms that I want to be activated when the player steps on them. Also potentially killing enemies by jumping on them. That's why I was thinking of a different fixture for the feet.

Comment: Checking the collision normal might be sufficient and simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. I think I got something basic working with print statements at the moment.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, feel free to post your solution as an Answer.